# Visualising hierarchical data with many nodes

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, hierarchical-data

I am visualising and comparing employment by industry at three levels of industrial classification in three cities. That's 5,354 data points. I need to beautify and clarify the visualisation to make it easy to compare the biggest industries within classification levels and across classification levels. Most industries are too small to distinguish individually at this scale, but they should be included anyway to compose the overall picture.

Here is a partition layout diagram (on Mac, Windows gives a less polished result):
[image]

The figures within the bars are industry codes, not employment numbers. Note that nested industries are aligned within the diagram.

Here is the code for the diagram:

```
# Order by descending NAICS code: KEY to diagram appearance
temp1 <- temp1[with(temp1, order(cbsa_name, naics_level, -naics)),]

# Plot partition layout/table
library(ggplot2)
lg2lb <- colorRampPalette(c("light green", "light blue"))(3)
textsize=14
pt <- theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), 
            panel.background=element_blank(), panel.border=element_blank(), 
            plot.title=element_text(size=textsize), legend.position="none", 
            legend.background=element_blank(), legend.key=element_blank(), 
            legend.justification=c(1,1), legend.text=element_text(size=textsize), legend.title=element_text(size=textsize), 
            axis.line=element_line(colour="black"), axis.text=element_text(size=textsize, colour="black"), 
            axis.title=element_text(size=textsize), strip.text.x=element_text(size=textsize), strip.background=element_blank())
ggplot(temp1, aes(naics_level, emp_est/1000, fill=factor(naics_level))) + pt + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 2565)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", size=.2, position='stack', col=1, width = 1) + scale_fill_manual(values=lg2lb) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=naics, size=emp_est/sum(emp_est)), position=position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + 
  facet_wrap(~cbsa_name, strip.position="top") + labs(x="Niveaux de nomenclature", y="Emploi 2015 (milliers)")
```

I want to improve the appearance of the diagram by managing smaller stacks better. I can think of several solutions but I don't know how to implement them. Which one do you think would work best? There might also be better ideas, even not involving this type of diagram.

1) Removing bar labels which are anyway too small to distinguish: 
I've tried replacing in the code above `size=emp_est/sum(emp_est)` by `size=ifelse(emp_est/sum(emp_est)>5, emp_est/sum(emp_est), 0)` but it doesn't work because it apparently sets all remaining labels at the same size. The problem might be that ifelse() doesn't work within aes(). See the outcome (produced on Windows this time):
[image]

2) Sizing bar labels so that they don't stick out of their bar at smaller sizes (as you can see they do in the first diagram above). What size function could help me there?

3) Replacing bundles of adjacent illegible bars by a single bar labelled "Many small industries here".

4) Any other ideas?

I'll try and post my data up here in a future edit.
EDIT: my data (too big to paste here): https://zerobin.net/?1faa4f697b2835fe#GjapzLQ1f/ncwNS5bqyh6tHpgE8sG2RMaKMZoYOA3Mk=

Comment: Your question is very specific so you have to post example data to test our solutions

Comment: @PoGibas I just did.

Comment: @R.S. I'm not sure I understand. Isn't it obvious from the diagram which industries are the biggest? The figures within the bars are industry codes, not employment numbers (I just edited the OP to reflect that). The idea is to quickly identify the biggest industries. Thanks for your suggestion about fill colours! (PS: I wanted to upvote your comment but you withdrew it for some reason.)

Comment: Ah, yes once I downloaded your data I realized they were industry codes not employment numbers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to print only industry codes with high employment.  I create a separate industry label and use that in `geom_text`.

```
# create industry label, set blank for employment < 50000
temp1$naics_label <- temp1$naics
temp1$naics_label[temp1$emp_est < 50000] <- ""

ggplot(temp1, aes(naics_level, emp_est/1000, fill=factor(naics_level))) + pt + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 2565)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", size=.2, position='stack', col=1, width = 1) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=lg2lb) +
  geom_text(aes(label=naics_label, size=emp_est/sum(emp_est)), position=position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + 
  facet_wrap(~cbsa_name, strip.position="top") + labs(x="Niveaux de nomenclature", y="Emploi 2015 (milliers)")
```

[image]

Another solution is to set `aes` fill colors to employment numbers to emphasize size of industry as it's hard to determine from stacked bars. I use color brewer palette in `scale_fill_distiller`.

```
pt2 <- theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), 
         panel.background=element_blank(), panel.border=element_blank(), 
         plot.title=element_text(size=textsize), 
         legend.justification=c(1,1), legend.text=element_text(size=textsize-2), legend.title=element_text(size=textsize), 
         axis.line=element_line(colour="black"), axis.text=element_text(size=textsize, colour="black"), 
         axis.title=element_text(size=textsize), strip.text.x=element_text(size=textsize), strip.background=element_blank())

ggplot(temp1, aes(naics_level, emp_est/1000, fill=emp_est)) + pt2 + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 2565)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", size=.2, position='stack', col=1, width = 1) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=naics_label, size=emp_est/sum(emp_est)), position=position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + 
  scale_fill_distiller("Emploi", type = "div", palette = "RdYlBu", direction = -1) +
  guides(size=FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~cbsa_name, strip.position="top") + labs(x="Niveaux de nomenclature", y="Emploi 2015 (milliers)")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Windows messes things up, so I have to tweak font sizes. In particular, bar labels are oversize. Applying any coefficient x to `size=x*emp_est/sum(emp_est)` strangely doesn't affect font size in the diagram. Do you know how to get around this?

Comment: I believe you can set range of min value and max value of the size parameter under `scale_size` -- "range: a numeric vector of length 2 that specifies the minimum and maximum size of the plotting symbol after transformation."  Something like `scale_size(range=c(0.5,2))` should work.